# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 4

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not able to identify the error in my code, could someone tell me what's wrong, have tried everything but can not find that this can be
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4.

I'm Brazilian, my variables will get a little complicated for you to understand, because I would not have edited a lot of work to change all the code

```
package Aulas_POO;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class edicoes {

    static byte espaço=10;
    static String pesquisa;
    static String informacoes[][] = new String [10][4];
    static String escolhaMenu;


    public static void main(String[] args) {




        String opcao="";


        do{
            opcao= ExibirMenu();

            if(opcao.equals("1")){  Cadastro(); }

            if(opcao.equals("2")){ pesquisa();  }

            if(opcao.equals("3")){  edicao();   }

            if(opcao.equals("4")){visualizar(); }

            if(opcao.equals("5")){deletarTudo();}

            if(opcao.equals("6")){deletarUm();  }

                                    }while(!opcao.equals("7"));


    }


    private static String ExibirMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

String menu  ="DIGITE UMA DAS OPÇÕES\n\n\n"
             +"1) Cadastro\n"
             +"2) Pesquisa de nomes\n"
             +"3) Edição de nomes\n"
             +"4) Visualizar a lista\n"
             +"5) Deletar todos cadastros\n"
             +"6) Deletar Apenas um cadastro\n"
             +"7) SAIR";

        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);



    }


    private static void deletarUm() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        pesquisa=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o Cpf");

        for (int i = 0; i < informacoes.length; i++) {


            if (pesquisa.equals(informacoes[i][1])){

                informacoes[i][0]=null;
                informacoes[i][1]=null;
                informacoes[i][2]=null;
                informacoes[i][3]=null;
        }


        }


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cadastro Deletado com SUCESSO!");

        }



    private static void deletarTudo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        for (int i = 0; i < informacoes.length; i++) {

        informacoes[i][0]=null; 
        informacoes[i][1]=null;
        informacoes[i][2]=null;
        informacoes[i][3]=null;
        }


    }

    private static void visualizar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String exibeInformacoes="";



        for (int i = 0; i < informacoes.length; i++) {


            if(!(informacoes[i][i]==null)){

            exibeInformacoes+="\nNome: "+informacoes[i][0]+", CPF: "+informacoes[i][1]+", CEP: "+informacoes[i][2]+" e Telefone: "+informacoes[i][3];


            }

                                }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,exibeInformacoes);

    }


    private static void edicao() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        pesquisa=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o CPF");

        escolhaMenu="Digite \n\n"+
                "1-Editar nome\n"+
                "2-Editar cep\n"+
                "3-Editar telefone\n"+
                "4-Editar todos\n"+
                "5-Sair";


        for (int i = 0; i < informacoes.length; i++) {




            if(escolhaMenu.equals("1")){
                informacoes[i][0]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o novo Nome");}

            if(escolhaMenu.equals("2")){
                informacoes[i][2]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o novo cep");}

            if(escolhaMenu.equals("3")){
                informacoes[i][3]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o novo telefone");}

            if(escolhaMenu.equals("4")){
                informacoes[i][0]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o novo Nome");
                informacoes[i][1]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o novo cpf");
                informacoes[i][2]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o novo cep");
                informacoes[i][3]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o novo telefone");}

            if(escolhaMenu.equals("5")){return;}

        }


    }


    private static void pesquisa() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        pesquisa=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o CPF");

        escolhaMenu="Digite \n\n"+
                    "1-Pesquisar nome\n"+
                    "2-Pesquisar cep\n"+
                    "3-Pesquisar telefone\n"+
                    "4-Pesquisar todos\n"+
                    "5-Sair";

        for (int i = 0; i < informacoes.length; i++) {


        if(pesquisa.equals(informacoes[i])){


            if(escolhaMenu.equals("1")){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,informacoes[i][0]);}
        }

        if(escolhaMenu.equals("2")){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,informacoes[i][2]);}




        if(escolhaMenu.equals("3")){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,informacoes[i][3]);}



        if(escolhaMenu.equals("4")){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n"+informacoes[i][i]);}

        }   

        if(escolhaMenu.equals("5")){
            return;
        }

}

    private static void Cadastro() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(espaço!=0){




        informacoes[0][0]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o nome");
        informacoes[0][1]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o cpf");
        informacoes[0][2]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o cep");
        informacoes[0][3]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o telefone");


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cadastro efetuado com SUCESSO!");


        espaço--;
}

else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não há mais espaço disponível , remova algum cadastro para novo cadastro");
}

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Your problem is probably that you didn't initialize the multidimensional array properly though.

Comment: @Antimony: The initialization looks valid to me: `static String informacoes[][] = new String [10][4];` It's not *nice*, splitting the type information like that, but it should work. See my answer for where I suspect the problem lies.

Comment: -1 for not posting the traceback.

Comment: Pretty sure your bug is here: `if(!(informacoes[i][i]==null)){`.  It makes no sense to have both indices the same, and it seems likely that `i` will exceed 3.

Comment: @Jon, I was just guessing since multidimensional array initialization is so commonly messed up. I didn't feel like hunting through such a large code sample with no traceback.

Comment: Please, a small effort to format the code would be appreciated (you can keep your brasilian variables but removing all the unnecessary line feeds would be nice!)

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, *please* cut down your code to just a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem, and if you're reporting an exception, include the stack trace and relevant line numbers.

I *suspect* that this is the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < informacoes.length; i++) {
    if(!(informacoes[i][i]==null)){
```

That's going to cause a problem when `i` is 4.

That may not be the *only* problem of course - your code may not have reached that far. It's relatively hard to read over 240 lines of code without any explanation of what you're trying to achieve, and an inadequate description of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jon, the error was the same, but not only that line, I have to edit all conditions that put on [i] [i] ... I thought leaving the position matrix percoreria 0-3 though she travels the 1-4 causing the error.

Comment: @user1660583: I didn't follow your second sentence at all - what does "percoreria" mean? But the problem is that `i` will go up to 10, because that's the length of `informacoes`.